# Cannot call a webapi from mac simulator when debugging from visual studio 2015 ionic apache cordova app

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-web-api2, visual-studio-cordova

Let me tell you my steps.

1. we are creating an **iOS** app using ionic framework template from Visual studio 2015
2. we created a asp.net webapi 2 with CORS enabled.we publish that into a public domain to access from anywhere.
3. we created a login page which will post userid and password to web api via http$ **code is written below**
4. **when we are running from VS2015 with ripple emulator we are able to see connection ok and api returning success data while pressing Login button**
5. we started remotebuild in our development mac machine

   > remotebuild --secure false
6. we configure VS2015 with remote agent configuration.
7. we started debugging and can see remotebuild is responding and our app with all images loaded successfully in ios simulator.
8. when we press login button on simulator debug point also comes to visual studio in windows machine.
9. **after api call result is null and status is 0**

**we tried every possible combination with local ip,global ip,dns names 
we tried installing cordova whitelist plugin.but same problem.**

> **Please help.**

```js
 var Paramdata = {
   USER_ID: data.username,
   COUNTRY_ID: data.CountryId.ID,
   PASSWORD: data.password
 };

 $http.get('http://www.myapp.com/AppApi/api/users?id=' + JSON.stringify(Paramdata)).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
     console.log("**** SUCCESS ****");
     console.log(status);
   })
   .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
     console.log("**** ERROR ****");
     console.log(status);
   })


 .then(function(response) {

       var jsonData = response.data;

       $scope.LoginData = jsonData;

       if ($scope.LoginData[0].isvalid == 'Y') {

         var alertPopup = $ionicPopup.alert({
             title: 'Login Sucessful!',
             template: LoginData[0].MESSAGE_LOGIN
           }
         } else {
           var alertPopup = $ionicPopup.alert({
             title: 'Login failed!',
             template: LoginData[0].MESSAGE_LOGIN
           })
         }
       });
```

Comment: Enable developer funcionalities on safari (desktop machine) to inspect and debug remotely the code running in the simulator or ios device

Comment: you need to specify two things: In config.xml the <access /> and in the html page add a content security policy. More info here http://taco.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/cordova-5-security/

Comment: another thing to consider, if you are using IOS9, and the webapi you are trying to hit is not https, you will also encounter an error. There is a Cordova plugin that can overcome that issue however.